# What is a Jira 'context'?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

What is a Jira 'context'?  What is the 'on the fly' context?

The documentation explains it as a set of issues, but that is not the only thing it is. Some contexts have exactly the same issues but I can do something in one context (such as prioritization) that I cannot do in another.

Comment: This refers to GreenHopper context, not JIRA, I believe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A context is a bundle of settings. Among the settings in the such bundle are

- Filters (for example I have a context "To Be Estimated" which filters out everything which should not be estimated (bugs), is already estimated or is not ready for estimation (not clear enough).
- Sorting: Only when sorting is done by a rank column you can use the Context for prioritizing issues.
- Highlighting

About the on the fly context the [Greenhopper wiki](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/GH/Using+Contexts+to+Filter+and+Highlight+Issues) is quite helpful I think:

> GreenHopper comes with 2 built-in contexts:
>
> **'On the fly' context** — A non-deletable context that will allow all logged-in users to build new contexts (See the 'Creating a New
>   Context' section below). Any changes that a user makes to this context
>   will only persist for the current session and will not be saved.
>
> **'Default' context** — A non-deletable context that only people with the
>   'Administer Projects' permission can edit and that is shared with all
>   users and anonymous users (if your project is public). It is very
>   important to note that editing this context will affect all users that
>   use that context.